# How to rewrite code to avoid TSLint "object access via string literals"

Tags: typescript, tslint

I'm pretty new to TypeScript and I would like to know if there exists a good way to rewrite code to avoid TSLint error "object access via string literals is disallowed" in the following code

```
interface ECType
{
    name: string;
    type: string;
    elementType?: string;
}

export var fields: { [structName: string]: Array<ECType>; } = { };

class ECStruct1 {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
    baz: boolean;
    qux: number;
    quux: number;
    corge: ECStruct2[];
    grault: ECStruct2;

    constructor() {
        ...
    }
} 

fields['ECStruct1'] = [
    { name: 'foo', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'bar', type: 'int' },
    { name: 'baz', type: 'bool' },
    { name: 'qux', type: 'long' },
    { name: 'quux', type: 'ulong' },
    { name: 'corge', type: 'array', elementType: 'ECStruct2' },
    { name: 'grault', type: 'ECStruct2' }
];
```

**Update**: At the end the content above will be part of a self-generated file with more than 300 `ECStruct`s, so I would like to have the class definition (e.g. `ECStruct1`) followed by its meta-description (e.g. `fields['ECStruct1']`).

Comment: I've never used TS but looking at the error and looking at the code, I'd say you need to replace `fields['ECStruct1']` with `fields.ECStruct1`. Using dot notation to access object props is usually preferred over string literal access.

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried it, but `fields.ECStruct1=` is not allowed by the TS compiler: Error TS2339 Property 'ECStruct1' does not exist on type '{ [structName: string]: ECType[]; }'.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

You have a couple options here:

**1) Just disable the rule**

```
/* tslint:disable:no-string-literal */
whatever.codeHere()
/* tslint:enable:no-string-literal */
```

**2) Use a variable instead of a string literal**

```
// instead of 
fields['ECStruct1'] = ...
// do something like
let key = 'ECStruct1';
fields[key] = ...
```

**3) Write/Generate an explicit interface**

See [MartylX's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33389446/3124288). Essentially:

```
interface ECFieldList {
    ECStruct1: ECType[];
}

export var fields:ECFieldList = {
    ECStruct1: [
        ...
```

---

Any of these are reasonable solutions, although I'm not as much of a fan of #2 because it's mangling up your code for no good reason. If you're generating code anyways, perhaps generating a type for `fields` as in #3 is a good solution.

Answer (score 59):

You can get rid of the rule. Look for `tslint.json`, the add a property `"no-string-literal"` with `false`, in `rules`::

```
{
"rules": {
    "no-string-literal": false,
    ... other rules ...
```

Answer (score 56):

Just use template literal annotation.

```
fields[`ECStruct1`]
```

Comment: Ugly trick as it defeats the purpose of the very warning. but it solves _my_ problem in a simple way.

Comment: depending on your config, this may create a new warning: ` should be ' (quotemark) tslint(1)

Answer (score 7):

What about this way? I don't know if you need the indexer (`[structName: string]: Array<ECType>;`) or not.

```
interface ECType {
    name: string;
    type: string;
    elementType?: string;
}

interface ECFieldList {
    ECStruct1: ECType[];
}

export var fields:ECFieldList = {
    ECStruct1: [
        {name: 'foo', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'bar', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'baz', type: 'bool'},
        {name: 'qux', type: 'long'},
        {name: 'quux', type: 'ulong'},
        {name: 'corge', type: 'array', elementType: 'ECStruct2'},
        {name: 'grault', type: 'ECStruct2'}
    ]
};
```

Comment: I edited my questions and added more details, so this comment should be clear. I would like to avoid having the `interface` with _N_ definitions of `ECStruct` and then the `export var fields...` where I write the actual definition of every `ECStruct`.

Comment: What is your settings for tslint? I guess you have enabled `no-string-literal` (disallows object access via string literals. - https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint)

Comment: Yes, now I have the option `no-string-literal` globally enabled and only in the file with the above code I disabled it with comment `/* tslint:disable: no-string-literal */`.

Comment: Well, use the bracket syntax with variables (i.e  `fields[variable]`) and dot syntax with strings (i.e. `fields.ECStruct1`) and you should be ok.

Answer (score 6):

Probably not the best option, but using

```
fields['ECStruct1'.toString()]
```

works too

Comment: Please do not do this. The linter is there because the person who set up the project wants you to follow best code practices, not hack around the linter rules.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to define a variable to hold the value of ECStruct1:

```
const sampleName = 'ECStruct1';
```

and then, get access to the object by using the variable as index:

```
fields[sampleName] ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error. but i tried to make use of the `type` of `Headers` of `Request` object and it worked for me. Below is how I managed to resolve the issue.

```
const objToAdd: { [key: string]: string } = {};
objToAdd.type = 'typeToAdd';
objToAdd.key = 'keyToAdd';
objToAdd.value = 'valueToAdd';
```

if you see the type `{ [key: string]: string }` tells the TSLint that this object takes keys and values of type string.
Similarly, `{ [key: string]: any }` types specifies that the keys are of `string` type and values of are of `any` type