# Angular 2 access via string literals is disallowed

Tags: angular, gulp, tslint

I'm new to AngularJS 2 and this is my first time trying to compile it with TSlint. I did [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) tutorial, and there is a part like the one below, which TSlint doesnt want to compile saying `object access via string literals is disallowed.`

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      let id = +params['id'];
      this.projectService.getProject(id)
        .then(project => this.project = project);
    });
  }
```

I'm not sure if I understand the problem and I'm lost if it comes to solving it. Could you help me, please?

**My other codes**

```
    getProjects(): Promise<Project[]> {
      return this.http.get(`${this.configuration.Server}projects${this.configuration.ApiUrl}`)
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

    getProject(ident: number): Promise<Project> {
      return this.getProjects()
             .then(projects => projects.find(project => project.id === id));
    }
```

Comment: Problem is not here. Show your getProject method.

Comment: Tried changing `params['id']` to `params.id`? Alternatively, you can re-configure your TSLint settings.

Comment: yes, it doesn't exist

Answer (score 7):

I would just get rid of this rule. Accessing a property by string, is sometimes necessary. If you look in your `tslint.json` file you should see the property [`"no-string-literal"`](http://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-string-literal/). Just change that to false.

If you want to keep the rule, then for this particular case, you can just type to the `params` to have an `id`. You can do this because [`Params` type](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.1.0-rc.0/modules/%40angular/router/src/shared.ts#L21) is simply `{[key: string]: any}`

```
route.params.subscribe((params: {id: string}) =>{
  let id = +params.id;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be fixed by assign a string literal to a variable. And use it inside the `[]`.refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387090/how-to-rewrite-code-to-avoid-tslint-object-access-via-string-literals), it has multiple options to resolve this issue.

Comment: doesn't help at all