# object access via string literals is disallowed ! while i try to access (route.params['id'] route param via dynamic id

Tags: angular, typescript

here is my  [app-routing.modulse.ts] module

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/recipes', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'recipes', component: RecipesComponent, children: [
        { path: '', component: RecipeStartComponent },
        { path: ':id', component: RecipeDetailComponent },
    ] },
    { path: 'shopping-list', component: ShoppingListComponent },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

here is childComponent RecipeDetailsComponent  ! and got error here while trying to access route params id

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from '../recipe.model';
import { RecipeService } from '../recipe.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-recipe-detail',
    templateUrl: './recipe-details.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./recipe-details.component.css']
})

export class RecipeDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    recipe: Recipe;
    id: number;
    constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
            // error lies below
            this.id = +params['id'];
            this.recipe = this.recipeService.getRecipe(this.id);
        });
    }
}
```

i got an error message "object access via string literals is disallowed" 
while trying to get an access to dynamic route params id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rewrite code to avoid TSLint "object access via string literals"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387090/how-to-rewrite-code-to-avoid-tslint-object-access-via-string-literals)

Comment: Please [**search**](/search?q=%5Btypescript%5D+object+access+via+string+literals+is+disallowed) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: i have serach before posting code . but i didnot find an suitable answere for me. any how thank you .

Answer (score 2):

Could you try this?

```
route.params.subscribe((params: {id: string}) => {
  this.id = +params.id;
})
```

**I'm modifying this based on the comments

Just update the appRoutes as

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
 { path: 'recipes', component: RecipesComponent, children: [
 { path: ':id', component: RecipeDetailComponent },
 { path: '', component: RecipeStartComponent },
  ] }, //add the rest......
```

Comment: Could you give a brief on what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to get values from route.params?