# How to access object via string literals in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I want to show users which I got in "data" variable

I got an warning on line which says "object access via string literals is disallowed (no-string-literal)"

```
this.crud = data['msg'];
```

My class :

```
export class CrudClass {
    public id?: string;
    public  name: string;
    public email: string;
    public password: string;
}
```

My Component :

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
    private crud: CrudClass[];

    constructor(private router: Router, private apiRoutes: ApiRoutesService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.readApp();
    }

    readApp() {
        this.apiRoutes.readApp().subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.crud = data['msg'];
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I would create an interface in ApiRouteService that includes the value you need to access, and define the return type of readApp() (in service) to be an observable of that type. Then you can access it via dot notation. Check this sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-npvara

Answer (score 3):

you can do it multiple ways

**First Just disable the rule**

```
/* tslint:disable:no-string-literal */
 this.crud = data['msg'];
/* tslint:enable:no-string-literal */
```

**Second Use a variable instead of a string literal**

change

`this.crud = data['msg'];`

to

```
let key='msg';
this.crud = data[key];
```

Or to disable it globally set `no-string-literal: false` in `tslint.config.json`

[Related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33394365/5621827)

Comment: You should rather disable the rule in the `tslint.json` file with `no-string-literal: false`, other than that I agree !

Comment: @MoHiTPaNdEy which one you tried can you show the updated code

Answer (score 0):

You can try like setting a let object to a value and set it to the data property

Like

```
let dataKey='msg';
this.crud = data[dataKey]
```